# Solve Equation of three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve this system equations. I found 2 solutions, but it's was effort algebra with the second equation and take $z=0$ in (1), you can see 2 solutions with $x=-2,2$ and $ y=1,-1$. 
$$
(1) \ x^2+xyz+5z^3=4\\
(2) \ 3x^2-y^2+5xy=2 
$$

Are you know any algorithm, or method, or technique to find others solutions (?)
I think that this system eq, have not other solutions in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit improving the title and adding two tags, but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1995719).

Answer (score 1):

The system has infinite solutions. From the second equation, we get that
$$y^2 - (5x)y + (2-3x^2) = 0 \implies y = \dfrac{5x \pm \sqrt{25x^2 - 4(2-3x^2)}}2$$
Hence, $$y = \dfrac{5x \pm \sqrt{37x^2 - 8}}2 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\star)$$
Choose any $x \in \left(-\infty, - \sqrt{\dfrac8{37}} \right] \bigcup \left[\sqrt{\dfrac8{37}} , \infty \right)$. We can obtain $y$ from $(\star)$.
Now after we get $x$ and $y$, solve the cubic equation in $z$ i.e.
$$5z^3 + (xy)z + (x^2-4) = 0$$ which always has at-least one real solution.

Comment: I wonder whether OP meant to specify integer solutions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But the OP mentions "I think that this system eq, have not other solutions in $\mathbb{R}$"

Comment: Ah. Never mind.